# Failed to install shell commands ENOTDIR このエラーを解決したい

Tags: atom-editor, command-line

terminalからAtomを起動したいのですが、うまくいきません。
調べたところでは、AtomのInstall Shell Commmandsからできるようになるとのことでしたが、下記メッセージが出てきてうまくいきません。

> Failed to install shell commands
>   ENOTDIR　not a directory, unlink '/usr/local/bin/atom'

対処法教えていただけると助かります。

Comment: 対象となるOSはなんでしょうか?

Comment: コマンドラインで `ls -ld /usr/local/bin/atom` を実行するとどう出力されますか?

Comment: @KiYugadgeter OS Xです

Comment: @masm　Not adirectoryって出ますね

Answer (score 1):

```
bash-3.2$ ls -ld /usr/local/bin/atom
ls: /usr/local/bin/atom: Not a directory
```

となる状況を意図的に作ってみました。

```
bash-3.2$ ls -ld /
drwxr-xr-x  30 root  wheel  1088 12  9 14:45 /
bash-3.2$ ls -ld /usr
drwxr-xr-x@ 12 root  wheel  408 12  9 12:28 /usr
bash-3.2$ ls -ld /usr/local
drwxr-xr-x  14 root  wheel  476  2 18 20:35 /usr/local
bash-3.2$ ls -ld /usr/local/bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  0  2 18 20:35 /usr/local/bin
bash-3.2$ ls -ld /usr/local/bin/atom
ls: /usr/local/bin/atom: Not a directory
bash-3.2$
```

この例の場合は、`/usr/local/bin` がディレクトリでなくファイルであるため、
`/usr/local/bin/atom` にアクセスしようとすると Not a directory となります。

このように、ディレクトリ階層のどこかがディレクトリでなくファイルになっていないか、
確認してみるのが良いと思います。

Comment: 確認してみます。ありがとうございます